# How to disable jumping to next line in div with float: left?

Tags: html, positioning, css-float

I have a problem as i've described in title. 
I've got menu and I use inside it float:left for divs.  Menu box contains search box and when i resize page i don't want search box to jump to next line when width of site is too little, i want to be "cut/hidden" this part of search box.

I've tried with inline-block, position:absolute, overflow:hidden and nothing works as i want to.

Sample (i want this green boxes to stay in first line and i don't want to have horizontal scroll bar because of hidden elements, also i want "content" to be able to resize even we pass size limit which guarantees to show every menu item ):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />

        <style>
          html, body {width:100%}
          #header { width: 100%; height: 50px; }
          #menu_box { width: 100%; height: 50px; background: red; }
          .menu_item { background: green; width: 100px; height: 25px; float: left; }
          #content{ width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="header">
          <div id="menu_box"> 
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        text which align is center
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

EDIT2, now you should understand what I mean, in this case it doesn't work properly, overflow:hidden do nothing (it was first thing which i've tried). Look at content. To avoid questions: yes, i need to use css tables.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />

        <style>
          html, body {width:100%}
          #header { display: table-cell; width: 100%; height: 50px; }
          #menu_box { width: 800px; height: 50px; background: red; overflow: hidden; }
          .menu_item { background: green; width: 100px; height: 25px; float: left;}
          #content{ display:table-cell; width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center; }

          .row { display: table-row; width: 100%; }
          #table {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="table">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="header">
                  <div id="menu_box"> 
                    <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
                    <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
                    <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
                    <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
                    <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
                    <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
                    <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
                    <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="content">
                LOOK AT THIS (when width of menu_box is constant and when isn't)<br>Try to resize this site
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize width on resize of window.
Here's the jQuery way,

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   // Change your search box width here relative to window's width
})
```

Here the css way,

```
<div style='width:800px'>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
            <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
          </div>
```

i.e. wrap it it a div and fix its width.

Comment: It's really ugly way. It's possible to be done without using JS, so i'd prefer to do it using only css/html.

Comment: You haven't included your code first.

Edited my answer, look at it.

Comment: It's the same as above. Yes, it solves problem of wraping items, but... "...and i don't want to have horizontal scroll bar because of hidden elements, also i want "content" to be able to resize even we pass size limit which guarantees to show every menu item" This solutions causes that scrollbar is visible and divs under header doesn't resizing to lower size any more. Scroll bar isn't a big problem, but it stops resizing.

Comment: May be I am not getting your question, but we cannot resize without javascript.

Comment: Now I know what I really want to do... Actually what I need is to make first row of table stop resizing when second row content will be still resizing, now when I get my mind around it, I see that it's impossible without using JS. So actually your idea to use onresize will be the solution eventhoug you didn't know what I meant :P. I was really confused before, because I was thinking about it in completly another way, to hide menu in header etc. (but i've forgotten that it won't be good, because actually on small resolution menu won't be available at all)

Comment: I am happy that you have got your answer :)
We all think stupid, sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Drogi Wojciechu :)

I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to achieve as you have provided us with no code samples, however I would try applying `white-space: nowrap;` to that area as this should prevent things from wrapping to the next line.

EDIT:

Based on the code sample, the easiest solution, provided that you always know how many items you will have, would be adding a wrapper around the green boxes, like so:

```
<div id="menu_item_wrapper">
        <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
        <div class="menu_item">sd</div>
    (....)
</div>
```

and then setting the width of the wrapper to `menu_item_width * number_of_items`, in this case 800px as there are 8 items and each item is 100px wide:

```
#menu_item_wrapper { width: 800px;}
```

This works when applied to your sample code. I would however suggest using `ul` and `li` instead of a bunch of divs.

Now, to get rid of the horizontal scroolbar you need to set the margin and padding of the body to 0:

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

That's because you have set the width of you menu_box to 100%, but your body still has paddings.

I hope I understand what you mean.

EDIT2:

I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean, but if you don't want a scrollbar to appear after you resize the window and the red boxes go beyond the window, apply `overflow:hidden;` to the red box like so:

```
#menu_box { width: 100%; height: 50px; background: red; overflow: hidden; }
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've already tried "white-space: nowrap;". I didn't give any code, because it's in my quite big project and it's hard to cut all css, divs etc. 

I've got div "header" inside which is "menu_box" which contains divs - menu options. That menu options jumps to next line. Applying white-space to "menu_box" do nothing, applying it also to outer "header" div causes that whole header isn't resizing (this "header" is inside div with display: table-row)

Comment: If you could share some code snippets and maybe a link to that page it will be easier for us to understand how the whole thing is built.

Comment: I know that trying to do that with "float: left" it's quite strange, because float as I think was designed to do such things like jumping to next line, but i haven't got another idea.

Comment: I've added a solution, I hope that helps.

Comment: look at my comment on the bottom :)

Comment: I've edited my question (now you should understand me, sorry for so much trouble)

Comment: But have you tried applying both the wrapper and overflow: hidden? Overflow by itself won't change anything. I still don't understand what are you trying to do. I don't know if this is allowed but you can try explaining it in Polish if you want to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7127/discussion-between-wojciech-kulik-and-mmm)